# How to make these two <div> inline?

Tags: css, html

I'm editing someone other's code, there's an existing form and css file, what I did is that I added 5 "select" tags into the form, and I want to make the selects inline.

Each select has a label, so I put them two in a div, thus I have 5 divs.
I want to put the first 3 div in one row, and last 2 in another row.
I was working on the css file for hours to get things work, but still failed.

The problem I'm getting now is that I cannot put the s in the same line, each of them occupies a separate line, so I have 5 rows in the form now... but I just need 2 rows.

Please help me on that, not quite familiar with CSS.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mrbs.css.php" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="css/mrbs-print.css.php" type="text/css">
    <form id="add_room" class="form_admin" action="addsystem.php" method="post">
      <fieldset>
      <legend>Add System</legend>

 <div id="sdw-div" style="white-space:nowrap; display:inline">     
    <label for = "sdw">sdw:</label>
    <select id="sdw" name="sdw" style="display:inline">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
       <option  value="1">1</option>
       <option  value="2">2</option>
       <option  value="3">3</option>
       <option  value="4">4</option>
     </select>
</div>

 <div id="etl-div" style="white-space:nowrap; display:inline">       
    <label for = "etl">etl:</label>
     <select id="etl" style="display:inline" name = "etl">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
        <option  value="1">1</option>
        <option  value="2">2</option>
        <option  value="3">3</option>
        <option  value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="hdm-div" style="white-space:nowrap; display:inline">       
    <label for = "hdm">hdm:</label>
     <select id="hdm" style="display:inline" name = "hdm">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
        <option  value="1">1</option>
        <option  value="2">2</option>
        <option  value="3">3</option>
        <option  value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div><strong>

.........other two are just the same....

</form>
</html></strong>
```

and here is the css file for form_admin

```
form.form_admin {float: left; clear: left; margin: 2em 0 0 0}
.form_admin fieldset {float: left; width: auto; border: 1px solid <?php echo $admin_table_border_color ?>; padding: 1em}
.form_admin legend {font-size: small}
.form_admin div {float:left; clear:left;}
.form_admin label {
    display: block; float: left; clear: left;
    width: <?php echo $admin_form_label_width ?>em; min-height: 2.0em; text-align: right;
}
.form_admin input {
    display: block; float: left; clear: right;
</strong>    width: <?php echo $admin_form_input_width ?>em;
    margin-top: -0.2em; margin-left: <?php echo $admin_form_gap ?>em;
    font-family: <?php echo $standard_font_family ?>; font-size: small;
}
.form_admin select {
    display: block; float: left; clear:right; margin-left: 1.0em;
}

.form_admin input.submit {
    width: auto; margin-top: 1.2em; margin-left: <?php echo number_format(($admin_form_gap + $admin_form_label_width), 1, '.', '')?>em
}
```

Comment: Use float and clear or add a <br /> tag before the div you want on the next line. 

[ http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp ]

[ http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp ]

Comment: the problem now is that I cannot get them in the same line, each <div> occupies a separate line...

Comment: Referring to your other comment: the "clear: left" style is causing your div to go to the next line, get rid of it, all your divs will line up next to each other. Add the clear style to the div you want to appear on the next line, it will give you the layout you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give div a `float:left;` css that will display them as inline.

Also remove `<strong>` from end of `html` tag.

#### **[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/BbrLX/1/)**

Comment: in the css file, I do have this attribute for <div>: .form_admin div {float:left; clear:left;}

Comment: @user1453951 i have added demo link to answer have a look

Comment: @user1453951 check the demo

Comment: Hi Dipesh, thanks, the demo looks pretty fine, it exactly what I want. And I changed my code according to your demo then tested it in jsfiddle, also works fine. But you know what? It still doesn't work on my local computer!!!!! what the hell is the problem...

Comment: @gtzinos : May i know what it does to you?

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
display:inline-block
```

i find it works better than elseware options

Answer (score 0):

Add style `float:left` for all five div. Also add a

```
<div style="clear:all"></div>
```

after third div. Also needed a parent container with proper width;

Comment: Thanks kuldeep, your suggestion is also very helpful, I think there might be something wrong in my local server, since the code works fine on jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

your `divs` are already `display:inline`, besides , you also have `float:left`-ed them.

still if they don't appear in the same line,then there is just one thing, your parent container doesn't have proper width to accommodate all the divs in same line.

so give appropriate width to your parent container

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/HrE39/1/). everything's working!